# como puedo tener la authorization bearer con curl en php?

Tags: php, curl

estoy trabajando con curl pero no se como obtener la bearer que regresa cuando haces una petición en postman  lo regresa aquí [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo sacar la authorization en curl para hacer una nueva petición con esta authorization así realizo la petición

```
    <?php    
    $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_URL => 
     "https://xxxxxxxx/rest/xxxxx",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 
      "xxx=xx&xx=xx&xx=xxx&xxxxx=xxxxxxx&undefined=",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "cache-control: no-cache"
       ),
       ));
      $responsess = curl_exec($curl);
      $err = curl_error($curl); 
       curl_close($curl);
```

como puedo optener la authorization bearer que regresa esa peticion en los headers

Comment: esto te puede orientar [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-headers.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

en el la configuracion de curl array agrego   CURLOPT_HEADER => true, y esto me  regresa la respuesta con los headers

Comment: Este post se reporto como de baja calidad. Por favor mira [answer]. Las respuestas tienen que ser completas y explicar el problema y la solución.